# The structure of the following sentence: "Why may standing up for a long time cause hypotension?"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is the structure of this sentence "Why may standing up for a long time cause hypotension?" correct?

Comment: *"Why may [X happen]?"* isn't idiomatically common in most contexts (it's a bit dated/formal/starchy). More likely are *"Why **does...**"* or *"How **can...**"*.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be? Please tell us who suggested it might not be and what exactly they said. ([Meta discussion](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5366/59258))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatical but, in a medical scenario I would use "how" instead of "why", and "can" instead of "may". It's just that hardly anybody uses "may" in ordinary conversation (or in medical schools) in AmE.

> Standing up for a long time can cause hypotension.
>
> How can standing up for a long time cause hypotension?

Some people are prone to hypotension when they keep in the standing position for a long time. Several factors can/may cause it.

Comment: Possibly not in this particular context, but _may_ is by far the most idiomatic verb to use when safeguarding against side effects: “may cause drowsiness, leprosy, exploding toes, and death”, etc. So if the subject of the sentence had been the name of some medication or other, rather than “standing up”, _may_ would have been preferable.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your're right.

Answer (score 0):

First, and most important,

> *Why may standing up for a long time cause hypotension?*

is a **rhetorical** question. No native English speaker would ever ask it as a real information-seeking question, 
unless prompted by some prior statement to use that ungrammatical construction with epistemic *may*.

Second, if it's a rhetorical question, then the important thing is the **answer**, not the question.
And the answer, viz

> *Standing up for a long time may cause hypotension because `Why`.*

is a normal use of epistemic *may*, from which the rhetoric question was crafted, via the normal rule of *Wh*-Question Formation. Except that the craftsman did not realize that many constructions with various epistemic and deontic modal auxiliaries are banned in some environments.

Like epistemic *may*, which is ungrammatical in questions.

- *This may be the place.* ==> **May this be the place?* ==> **Why may this be the place?*

I'd normally say something like *Can this be the place?* or *What makes you think that?*, instead.

Comment: Is *rhetorical* really the right term for a question that is answered straightaway?

Comment: Forgive me for being dense, but which part of your answer is about the correctness of the sentence structure?  I don't think the question is about good style.  I don't object to comments about style in an answer - I do that myself, often - but I usually try to answer the main question first.  If I didn't, I would only be making a comment.

Comment: @TimLymington Yes.  Asking rhetorical questions and answering them immediately yourself is itself a rhetorical device (there is probably a name for it, which somebody more learned than I could provide).  Donald Rumsfeld was notorious for it during his time as Bush's Secretary of Defense.  It may have been his way of avoiding answering the question he had been asked, but it was not invalid English.

Comment: @itsbruce: Epistemic _may_ is ungrammatical in questions. That means the structure of the sentence is not correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems grammatical to me, though *might* would be better.

Comment: Yes, _might_ is grammatical there, where _may_ isn't. These are just random facts about random modals, like fact that the epistemic sense of _will_ does not occur in hypothetical clauses. We say _if it rains tomorrow_ but not **if it will rain tomorrow.*

Answer (score -1):

If the sentence is asking for information, I think using "might" or "could" instead of "may" would be more correct. If it is like a blog title or something, and you want it to be a grammatically correct sentence, it should be something like "Learn why standing may..." or "Find out why..."  If you don't care about grammar, the trendy "BuzzFeed" way of doing it would be "Why standing may..."

Comment: There is absolutely nothing grammatically about "Why may standing... ?", either as a genuine question or as a rhetorical question being used as a title.  Using that in a title isn't even bad style; it is established, perfectly good style.

Comment: Fact. It's just not common sentence structure, as per the original post.

Comment: It is perfectly sensible.  It is a rhetorical question, used to signal clearly to the audience that a particular problem (or contentious point) is going to be investigated and answered.  Absolutely nothing wrong with the style.  And if you think it *is* grammatically correct, why did you say "If you want it to be correct, it should be different"?

Comment: The use of the word may there connotates getting permission. I assumed the poster meant "why can this possibly happen?" If you don't like my answer, provide a better one.

Comment: Your claims about grammar in your original statement are simply wrong and you have given no argument to back them up.  There isn't even anything wrong with the "trendy" alleged Buzzfeed style.  Telling critics to write their own answers is not an argument.

Comment: Ok. The phrase "Why standing may cause hypotension" is certainly not a complete sentence. We'll start there.

Comment: Answering qestions on about English grammar may cause altercations

Comment: **A)** You're now criticising an example you gave, not the OP's question. **B)** You're wrong. That *is* a complete sentence, just a minor one (which is perfectly acceptable and not at all uncommon in a title(.  But point **A** is more relevant, in any case.  You have not directly answered the question at all.  The fact that the points in your answer are specious and cannot be backed up is actually secondary.

Comment: The use of _may_ in this context quite obviously has nothing to do with permission, nor does it connotate anything of the kind (_might_, as you suggest, is just as much about permission, only in the past tense, as _may_ is). It expresses possibility.